# Variáveis locais e globais Python

Tags: python, variáveis, escopo-de-variáveis, declaração-de-variável, variáveis-globais

Tenho um software que trata datas, escrito da seguinte maneira:

```
def EscolheDataInicio():
    controle1 = None
    controle2 = None
    if controle1 == None:
        teste = easygui.ccbox(msg="Escolher data início?", title="Escolher data de início", choices=('[O]k', '[C]ancel'))
        if teste == False:
            controle1 = 1
        else:
            while controle1 == None:
                controle1 = easygui.enterbox(msg="Insira data início", title="Definir data início")
                ValidaDataInicio() #Testa se a entrada corresponde a uma data em formato válido...
                EscolheDataFim() #Chama função correlata para inserção de data final do intervalo.
```

A ideia é setar um intervalo de datas (`controle1` e `controle2`) **OU** setar uma data de referência padrão determinada pelo sistema (caso o usuário cancele a CCBOX, o programa assumirá que ele **não pretende** inserir um intervalo de datas, e setará `controle1` como `1`, saindo do loop.

A dúvida é: como MANTER esse `1`, para que o programa NÃO ENTRE na função novamente, já que eu declaro `controle1` como `None` como variável LOCAL a cada chamada? Já tentei declarar `controle1` como `None` FORA da função, e inserir um `global controle1` na função, mas aí ela retorna o erro `"NameError: name 'controle1' is not defined"`.

Quero que ele pergunte esse intervalo **uma vez**.

Na vdd o código todo é bem mais extenso, mas basicamente é isso:

```
controle1 = None
controle2 = None
def EscolheDataInicio():
    global controle1
    global controle2
    if controle1 == None:
        teste = easygui.ccbox(msg="Escolher data início?", title="Escolher data de início", choices=('[O]k', '[C]ancel'))
        if teste == False:
            controle1 = 1
        else:
            while controle1 == None:
                controle1 = easygui.enterbox(msg="Insira data início", title="Definir data início")
                ValidaDataInicio()
                EscolheDataFim()
```

Comment: E tem certeza que o erro de variável não definida ocorreu nesta função?

Comment: O erro dá na line 4 in EscolheDataInicio...

Comment: Veja: https://ideone.com/2TRiD9. Funciona como esperado. O erro deve estar em outra parte do código.

Comment: Estava declarando na biblioteca principal. Não sabia que o Python fazia essa diferenciação. Tenho uma biblioteca que "inicia" o programa, e outra apenas para o tratamento das datas. Coloquei o from `TrataAsDatas import *`, mas realmente não sabia disso. Grato.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Que tal:

```
import datetime
import easygui

# Declara lista global contendo o intervalo de datas e um flag indicador
g_intervalo_data = [ False, None, None ]

def ValidaData( data ):
    try:
        datetime.datetime.strptime( data, '%d/%m/%Y')
    except ValueError:
        return False
    return True

def EscolheDatas():

    # Faz com que a variavel global seja acessivel dentro do escopo da função
    global g_intervalo_data;

    dataInicio = None
    dataFim = None

    # Verifica se a pergunta já foi feita anteriormente verificando o flag indicador
    if( g_intervalo_data[0] == True ):
        return g_intervalo_data[1:3];

    opt = easygui.ccbox(msg="Escolher data inicio ?", title="Escolher data de inicio", choices=('[O]K', '[C]ancelar'))

    if opt == True:

        while True:
            dataInicio = easygui.enterbox(msg="Insira data inicio:", title="Definir data inicio" )
            if (dataInicio == None) or (ValidaData( dataInicio ) == True): break
            easygui.msgbox("Data Inicio Invalida!")

        while True:
            dataFim = easygui.enterbox(msg="Insira data final:", title="Definir data final" )
            if (dataFim == None) or (ValidaData( dataFim ) == True): break
            easygui.msgbox("Data Final Invalida!")

    # Preenche variavel global com o intervalo de data e um flag indicador
    g_intervalo_data = [ True, dataInicio, dataFim ]

    return g_intervalo_data[1:3];


print(EscolheDatas());
print(EscolheDatas());
print(EscolheDatas());
```

Comment: Vou testar @Lacobus! Grato!